# Lightdm doesn't work properly

Tags: lightdm, gdm

I have gnome installed on my `Ubuntu 12.10` and I am `using gdm as default display manager`. But the greeter for gdm is not working properly and whenever I `try to switch back to Lightdm` the `GUI just doesn't comes up`. All it shows is the various service starting display & then nothing happens.

The file I edit to change my default display manager is :

`/etc/X11/defualt-display-manager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`. This will open up a new window allowing you to select either gdm or lightdm as the default login display manager.

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` instead.

Comment: Well for sure that solved the `default manager` problem with `lightdm`, But the `greeter` doesn't seems to be working right as the background at the login screen comes in pretty dull and boring solid color and the icons too are showing pretty scrambled